# Generate Struts 2 JSON Output within Action Call

Tags: java, json, serialization, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

I'm currently working on making an Struts 2 Action call with a JSON response - I'd like to have the response be cache-able, which means I need to get the JSON generated within the code before the call is made. Something like this, within and action's execute() method:

```
String json = this.getJSONOutput();
JSONCacheUtils.cache(hash, json);
```

Is there any way to do this using the Struts 2 JSON library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Struts2 JSON plugin API to [serialize](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-plugins/struts2-json-plugin/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/json/JSONUtil.html#serialize%28java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) object. The same way `JSONResult` is doing when it's executed.

```
String json = JSONUtil.serialize(rootObject, excludeProperties, includeProperties, ignoreHierarchy, enumAsBean, excludeNullProperties);
```